# How to import self-made component into index.js in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning react and i'm stuck on how to import a self-made component.

So I made this into `src/components/Part/Part.jsx`

And in my index.js file I import this like that `import { Part } from './components/Part/Part.jsx';`

```
const Part = (props) =>{
    return (
    <p>{props.part + " " + props.exec}</p>
    )
  }

  export default Part
```

Comment: Where do you want to import? The `Part` is exported as default so you should use `import Part from './components/.../Part.jsx'`

Answer (score 1):

If your folder structure like -

```
src
|_components
  |__Part
    |__Part.jsx
    |__index.js
```

And want to export the `Part.jsx` from `index.js` then you can write this line into the `index.js` file.

```js
// At src/components/Part/index.js file
export {default} from './Part.jsx';
```

And now you can import the `Part` component from anywhere like-

```js
import Part from 'path/to/components/Part';
```

**Update:** You can follow the structure this allows you to import the component like `import Part from './components/Part'` instead of `import Part from './components/Part/Part.jsx'`.

Comment: My index.js file is in src/index.js and not into Part

Comment: So i have import Part from './components/Part/Part.jsx'; in my index.js file

Comment: You still can follow this file structure. Just create an `index.js` file inside the `Part` directory and write down the single line of code. This allows you to import the component like `from 'path/to/component/Part'` instead of `from 'path/to/component/Part/Part.jsx'`.

Comment: As you want to import the `Part` component to `src/index.js` file then write the import like `import Part from './components/Part'`. This is enough now.

Answer (score 1):

In your import statement remove curly brackets. It will work then. :)

Update this:

```
import { Part } from './components/Part/Part.jsx';
```

To:

```
import Part from './components/Part/Part.jsx';
```

For better understanding read **named exports** and **default exports** here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: I don't understand why I have this error in my Part.jsx file :      Line 3:5:  'React' must be in scope when using JSX

Comment: You need to import React in Part.jsx file because Part is a react component as it returns HTML.
Just put this as first line of Part.jsx:

import React from 'react';

It should fix the problem.